# my class is an "int" when I use it as an inheritance Attribute Error, what is the solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributeerror

The code is

```
class Raw:
    def __init__(he,dx=0,dy=0,ax=0,ay=0,rx=1.1,ry=1.1):
        #   Position
        input('Type{0}'.format(type(he)))
        he.x = 0
        he.y = 0
        #   Texture
        he.src = srcNone()
        he.isNoneSrc = 1
        #
        he.dx, he.dy = dx, dy
        #
        he.ax, he.ay = ax, ay
```

my class is an "int" when I use it as an inheritance, what is the solution
It is the code of the class that is transformed into "int" when it is used as an inheritance.

The code of the class that uses this class for inheritance:

```
class WithSrc(Raw):
    def __init__(he,src,dx=0,dy=0,ax=0,ay=0):
        print('Type Raw',type(Raw))
        Raw.__init__(dx,dy,ax,ay)
        he.changeTexture(src) #he.src = src
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\_Raphaël\code\Rgame code\ProgrammeN1\p1.py", line 47, in <module>
    ecran['Test'] = WithSrc(image.load('Scoeur.png'))
  File "D:\programme\lib\Rgame\PreClass.py", line 75, in __init__
    Raw.__init__(dx,dy,ax,ay)
  File "D:\programme\lib\Rgame\PreClass.py", line 27, in __init__
    he.x = 0
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'
```

The code output:

```
Type Raw <class 'type'>
Type<class 'int'>
```

This means that before using the method **init**() Raw was of type "type" then it is transformed into type "int" one the method **init** use.

Thank you for helping sorry for the English not very good, I am French.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "the class is transformed into 'int'" ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\_Raphaël\code\Rgame code\ProgrammeN1\p1.py", line 47, in <module>
    ecran['Test'] = WithSrc(image.load('Scoeur.png'))
  File "D:\programme\lib\Rgame\PreClass.py", line 75, in __init__
    Raw.__init__(dx,dy,ax,ay)
  File "D:\programme\lib\Rgame\PreClass.py", line 27, in __init__
    he.x = 0
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: Thank you for asking the question. It made me read my code again.

Comment: Not directly related, but tangental: by convention, the first parameter of an instance method should be named `self`. It's not *wrong* to name it `he`, as you've done here, but it's confusing. [PEP 8 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) "Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods."

Answer (score 1):

In this section :

```
Raw.__init__(dx,dy,ax,ay)
```

You are calling `Raw.__init__`. But look what arguments it takes :

```
def __init__(he,dx=0,dy=0,ax=0,ay=0,rx=1.1,ry=1.1):
```

The `he` is missing when you call it, so it is equivalent to :

```
Raw.__init__(he=dx,dx=dy,dy=ax,ax=ay)
```

So no, your class hasn't transformed into `int`. But `dx` is indeed an `int`, and therefore has no attr `x`. You need to add `he` to your initialization :

```
Raw.__init__(he,dx,dy,ax,ay)
```